# How I prove absolute convergence of this infinite product?

Tags: gamma-function, weierstrass-factorization

Why does the 1/n term needs to be 0 in order to have absolute convergence for the product? $$P=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }u_n=\prod \frac{(n-a_1)(n-a_2)...(n-a_n)}{(n-b_1)(n-b_2)...(n-b_n)}$$
$$u_n=1-\frac{a_1+a_2+...a_n-b_1-b_2-...b_n}{n}+O(n^{-2})$$

I also tried to solve it but I get $P=\coprod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\Gamma (1-b_i)}{\Gamma (1-a_i)}e^\frac{b_i}{a_i} $
Could you show me the calculations in order to get the right answer?
Whitch is $P=\coprod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\Gamma (1-b_i)}{\Gamma (1-a_i)}$ and help calculate with this product: $pi /2=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please if you need help take the time to TYPE your problem, the content of the pictures can't be indexed to be searchable.

Comment: Ok I will fix it asap

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tha infinite product $\prod (1+\alpha_n)$ **converges absolutely** (definition) iff
the series $\sum \alpha_n$ converges absolutely.
In this case, the rational function $u_n$ satisfies
$$
u_n = 1 + \frac{A}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\qquad\text{as }n\to\infty
$$
for some constant $A$.
Now $u_n = 1+\alpha_n$.  If $A \ne 0$, then $|\alpha_n| \sim \frac{|A|}{n}$,
so $\sum |\alpha_n|$ diverges by comparison with the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.  So $\sum \alpha_n$ does not converge absolutely.
So $\prod u_n$ does not converge absolutely.  So it remains only
to compute $A$ in this case:
$$
A = a_1 + a_2 + \dots+ a_k - b_1 - b_2 -\dots - b_k .
$$
If this is not zero, then the product does not converge absolutely.

Comment: if A=0 doesnt that mean that the product is 1?

Comment: If $A=0$ then the term looks like $u_n = 1+B/n^2+O(1/n^3)$.  So $\prod u_n$ need not be $1$.

Comment: and why I dont take into consideration the terms of 0(1/n^2)+ F(1/n^3)+... ?

Comment: How can I prove that $pi /2=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}$

Comment: I figured it out thanks for the help @GEdgar